# Possible to do inline code in ASPX markup?

Tags: c#, asp.net, inline

Is it possible to do things in a PHPish way in ASP.Net? I've seen `<%= %>` but I've tried it and couldn't get it to work.

The PHPish equivalent of what I want to do is

```
<script src="<?php echo ResolveUrl("jquery/js/jquery.js"); ?>"></script>
```

Comment: why you can't use the absolute path? because you your localhost virtual directory vs no virtual directory on live environment?

Comment: You really want to use this with caution though as "best practices" usually say to keep your UI and logic separate as possible.

Comment: @Dai yes I know but adding a literal control and modifying it in the code-behind seems really dirty. @Claudio. I ran into a problem where in development our virtual path is `/` and in production our path is `/product`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's quite possible.  You should familiarize yourself with all the variations of the (so called) alligator tags though.

Put code in between `<% %>` blocks.   The `<%= %>` variant is a shortcut for `Response.Write`, and is used as a shortcut for directly outputting a variable to the page.

The following should work, as long as ResolveUrl is returning a string.  Notice there is no ";" to end the line though.

```
<script src="<%= ResolveUrl("jquery/js/jquery.js") %>"></script>
```

Comment: Just to make a note, I later changed my code to use `<%# %>` instead because of this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778952/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-blo

Comment: Don't forget <%: %> in asp.net 4.0 for HtmlEncoding