# How can I use runat="server" on a script tag in asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, relative-path, script-tag, runatserver

I don't necessarily need to run it at server, however, I would like to use the `~/js/somefile.js` syntax.

Previously, I had just set everything with Absolute paths and set my project to be at the root level. SO, I'd just declare all my stylesheets, background images and javascript files something like `/css/somefile.css`

However, for this project, it doesn't run as root.

I can't put `runat="server"` on a script tag.

I can put it on a link tag, though.

This must be a common problem with a few simple answers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What I've always done is use a normal `script` tag and put the `src` in `<% %>` tags, as illustrated [here](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/the_script_tag_runatserver_problem_solution_using_resolveurl.aspx):

```
<script language="javascript" src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/App_Themes/MainTheme/jquery.js")%>' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Comment: Thanx! Yes, now I remember seeing this before.

Comment: Just an FYI, according this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778952/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-blo it's better to use # (DataBinding Expression) and Bind from behind.

Comment: @dl-_-lb: Never saw that before, but it makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: For some, an additional tip that might help if they get the "Controls collection cannot be modified" exception is to wrap the above method in a <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder> tag.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the ScriptManager for this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/somefile.js" />
        </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: I have in the past done this, yes... I wonder what the best way is though. Does this add any other overhead?

Comment: ScriptManager (or ToolkitManager) is generally the ideal choice in ASP.NET Webforms.

Answer (score 5):

You can get fully what you want by wrapping script tag with **asp:ContentPlaceHolder**
and the you can access it from code behind, for example set will it be executed or not by setting **visible** property to **true** or **false**.
Here is the example:

```
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PrintPreviewBlock" Visible="false">
    <script id="PrintPageCall" type="text/javascript" >
        $(function() {
            window.print();
        });
    </script>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

and from code behind:

```
PrintPreviewBlock.Visible = true;
```

Comment: This only works if you're putting it in a `.master` file; you can't do this in a regular aspx web page.

Answer (score 3):

You can use functions inside the path string, though, e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js") %>"></script>
```

However that's the ASP.NET MVC syntax for local paths - I can't remember the forms version off the top of my head.

Comment: forms version is the same. MVC syntax is inherited from web forms.

Comment: @Joel I meant the `UrlHelper` class that I'm using is MVC-only. As the others beat me to, the forms version is `ResolveUrl` on `System.Web.UI.Control`.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [dailycoding.com](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/the_script_tag_runatserver_problem_solution_using_resolveurl.aspx):

```
<script language="javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/[PATH]")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```