# Building a URL using any field

Tags: asp.net, webforms

In the WebForms application, ASP has such an address:

```
http://localhost:44444/User.aspx?u=1
```

The application uses the ID from the database by default as a field supported in the address

How to get down to the issue of replacing the current field?

In the database I added a column with UUID and I would like it to be used when displaying the URL

An example where a page from the above address is opened:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="UserID" 
        DataNavigateUrlFormatString="User.aspx?u={0}" DataTextField="LoginName"  
        HeaderText='USERNAME'>
</asp:HyperLinkField>
```

Comment: Are you doing this based on what the user requests (e.g. what url they provide you, or are you building a url to throw out to the user)? You can get the value of a url parameter with `Request.QueryString["u"];`

Comment: @UK_Dev The address is created in the application. The user can not change anything and create it manually in the URL

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515602/how-can-i-use-runat-server-on-a-script-tag-in-asp-net) might be of use with scriptlets `<%%>`