# The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)

Tags: c#

I am trying to create dynamic meta tags in C# but it gives the following error:

> The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control
>   contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)

This is the code I added:

```
HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();
meta.Name = "keywords";
meta.Content = "book,paper";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(meta);
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: you must have script tags in your .aspx markup

Comment: Can you show where you have the <% .. %> in your code?

Comment: Is there any way i can add code through c# for dynamic tags

Comment: <asp:Content ID="header" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
 
 </asp:Content>  this is how my code looks in aspx

Answer (score 191, accepted):

It's hard to tell for sure because you haven't included many details, but I think what is going on is that there are `<% ... %>` code blocks inside your `Page.Header` (which is referring to `<head runat="server">` - possibly in a master page). Therefore, when you try to add an item to the Controls collection of that control, you get the error message in the title of this question.

If I'm right, then the workaround is to wrap a `<asp:placeholder runat="server">` tag around the `<% ... %>` code block. This makes the code block a child of the Placeholder control, instead of being a direct child of the `Page.Header` control, but it doesn't change the rendered output at all. Now that the code block is not a direct child of `Page.Header` you can add things to the header's controls collection without error.

Again, there is a code block somewhere or you wouldn't be seeing this error. If it's not in your aspx page, then the first place I would look is the file referenced by the `MasterPageFile` attribute at the top of your aspx.

Comment: Thanks it worked i wrapped my css content with different placeholder it worked.

Comment: I tried adding just <div> with no runat=server attribute. It didn't work. So added the placeholder and it worked great.

Comment: For clarification is that workable inside a script tag? Or is it place a placeholder around the script tag?

Comment: SO is proof that old code doesn't have to die...because legacy never dies...Thank you for helping me solve this head-scratcher!

Comment: Working on an old web forms project and this saved me from a migraine.

Answer (score 20):

Just in case if you are using Telerik components and you have a reference in your javascript with <%= .... %> then wrap your script tag with a RadScriptBlock.

```
 <telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="radSript1" runat="server">
   <script type="text/javascript">
        //Your javascript
   </script>
</telerik>
```

Regards Örvar

Comment: This worked for me. Wonder why this was an issue without the <telerik:RadScriptBlock> tag.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the solutions at ["The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778952/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-bl)

The [accepted solution on the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1176779/1037948) worked for me -- change instances of `<%=` to `<%#`, which converts the code block from `Response.Write` to an evaluation block, which isn't restricted by the same limitations.

In this case though, like the [accepted solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4995628/1037948) suggests, you should add the controls to something other than a masterpage ContentPlaceHolder element, namely the `asp:Placeholder` control suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue that I solved this way:

Instead of adding the meta to the current page header that caused the same error as you had:

```
Page.Header.Controls.Add(meta);
```

I used this instead:

```
 Master.FindControl("YourHeadContentPlaceHolder").Controls.Add(meta);
```

and it works like a charm.

Comment: We are building parts of a page purely via code, and this ended up being our probiem, as well as the solution (add it to the Head placeholder if you have one in your master page). Strangely enough, this was only a problem on certain environments, not all, so it may be a configuration issue somewhere as well. Either way, this worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For those using Telerik as mentioned by Ovar, make sure you wrap your javascript in

```
 <telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="radSript1" runat="server">
   <script type="text/javascript">
        //Your javascript
   </script>
</telerik>
```

Since Telerik doesn't recognize <%# %> when looking for an element and <%= %> will give you an error if your javascript code isn't wrapped.

Answer (score 1):

Inside ContentPlaceholder, put the placeholder control.For Example like this,

```
<asp:Content ID="header" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
       <asp:PlaceHolder ID="metatags" runat="server">
        </asp:PlaceHolder>
</asp:Content>
```

Code Behind:

```
HtmlMeta hm1 = new HtmlMeta();
hm1.Name = "Description";
hm1.Content = "Content here";
metatags.Controls.Add(hm1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really solve your question but it's an important alternative.

If you want to add custom html to the beginning of the page (inside `<body>` element), you may use `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock()`.

Although the method is called "script", but you can add arbitary string, including html.