# The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% … %> ) adding the controls dynamically having Masterpages

Tags: c#, asp.net

The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% … %> ) when adding the controls dynamically having Masterpages

I am trying to add an HiddenField control to the aspx page. I am getting the below mentioned error

> The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% … %> ).

This happens when I have to add the controls dynamically. On the net, I found all the types of answers to add <%# instead of <%=. In my case this is not applicable at all.

Here is my code sample,

```
 HiddenField hndGuid = new HiddenField();
_page.Form.Controls.Add(hndGuid);
```

any pointers?

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace wwwroot.Common
{

    public class GuidClass
    {
        public GuidClass()
        {
            //
            // TODO: Add constructor logic here
            //
        }

        private string guid;

        public string Guid
        {
            get
            {
                return guid;
            }

            set
            {
                guid = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public class Myhandler : System.Web.UI.Page, IHttpModule
    {
        Page _page = null;
        HiddenField hndGuid = null;

    Queue<string> temp;
    public Myhandler()
    {
        temp=new Queue<string>();
    }
    public new void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {

        context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(context_PreRequestHandlerExecute);
    }


    void context_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        System.Web.HttpContext _httpContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;


        if (_httpContext != null)
        {
            _page = _httpContext.Handler as System.Web.UI.Page;

            if (_page != null)
            {

                _page.Init += new EventHandler(_page_Init);

                _page.Load += new EventHandler(_page_Load);
                hndGuid = new HiddenField();
                hndGuid.ID = "hndGuid";

            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }

    }

    void _page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        _page.Form.Controls.Add(hndGuid);

        if (!_page.IsPostBack)
            hndGuid.Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    }

    void _page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GuidClass currentGuid =new GuidClass();
        currentGuid.Guid = hndGuid.Value;
        System.Web.HttpContext _httpContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;

        if (temp.Contains<string>(currentGuid.Guid))
        {
            _httpContext.Items.Add("IsRefresh",true);
        }
        else
        {
            if(!(currentGuid.Guid.Equals(null)||currentGuid.Guid.Equals("")))
                temp.Enqueue(currentGuid.Guid);
            _httpContext.Items.Add("IsRefresh",false);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide to relevant mark-up code also.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778952/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-bl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995274/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-blo

Answer (score 0):

move the code blocks into a separate user control, no code behind required

http://csharpin.blogspot.com/2011/05/about-the-controls-collection-cannot-be.html