# Getting error when i put script element in head section of master page in asp.net 4.0 application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-4.0

I have User.master page in asp.net 4.0 application.
I wrote the following code in head section:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>SampleApp</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <script src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js")%>' type="text/javascript" language="javascript"/>
</head>
```

when i run the application i got following error:
[image]

Is there anything wrong in this code?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995274/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-blo

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap it inside a placeholder it should work.

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="script" runat="server">
    <script src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js")%>' type="text/javascript" language="javascript"/>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```