# Issue while using ajax calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am using Ajax calendar in an ASP.NET application like below lines of codes

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDOB" placeholder="(mm/dd/yyyy)" runat="server" onchange="ValidateDate()">
</asp:TextBox>

<ajax:CalendarExtender ID="txtDOBCalendar" runat="server" Format="mm/dd/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtDOB">
</ajax:CalendarExtender>
```

It is not working. It throws error message like

> "The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control
>   contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)."

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/4995628/3540365

Comment: The page works fine when we remove ajax calendar... please help me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there must be some code block **<%= ...%>**. Replace it with **<%# ...%>**. Hope it helps.