# Why I get error when I try to use variable of form class from designer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In code behind I have property called `ReportFeatures` and `Page_Load` event:

```
    public partial class FeatureList : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected string ReportFeatures;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IEnumerable<ReportFeature> featureProps = fim.getFeatureProperties();

            ReportFeatures = featureProps.ToJson();
        }
    }
```

In designer I tried to access ReportFeatures variable:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.reportFeatures = <%= ReportFeatures%>;
    </script>
</head>
```

When page loaded I get this error:

```
The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).
```

Any idea why I get that error, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<%= ... %>` block, try using data binding expression syntax (`<%# ... %>`), because `<%= ... %>` implicitly calls `Response.Write()` method in `Page.Header` which counts as code block while data binding expression doesn't count:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.reportFeatures = <%# ReportFeatures %>;
    </script>
</head>
```

Then add `Page.Header.DataBind()` method in `Page_Load` event, because you want to bind `ReportFeatures` inside `<head>` tag which contains `runat="server"` attribute:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IEnumerable<ReportFeature> featureProps = fim.getFeatureProperties();

    ReportFeatures = featureProps.ToJson();

    // add this line
    Page.Header.DataBind();
}
```

More details about this issue can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995274/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-blo).