# Can't use ajaxfileupload from control kit in ASP.NET 4.5

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I just installed ajax control kit 'cause i wanted to use ajax file upload since it's way better than the basic file upload. Problem is, whenever I open the page where i dragged the control to I have this exception

The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

I don't understand what it means with this. The only thing I have with <% %> are the bundle scripts in the head tag but i need those references

tried adding handler of ajax in web config but it doesn't work. i added it inside system.webServer like in an example and i stopped getting this exception

```
<handlers>
    <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" 
      path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd"
      type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, 
      AjaxControlToolkit"/>
</handlers>
```

EDIT:

Ok I got it to work, i am using bundle for references and i had this on the header on master page

```
  <%: Styles.Render("~/Content/adminlte") %>
<%: Styles.Render("~/Content/animate") %>
<%: Styles.Render("~/Content/fontawesome") %>
<%: Styles.Render("~/Content/iziToast") %>
<%: Styles.Render("~/Content/noty") %>
<%: Styles.Render("~/Content/css") %>
<%: Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/jquery") %>
<%: Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/adminlte") %>
<%: Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/jqueryval") %>
<%: Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/bounce") %>
<%: Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/fontawesome") %>
<%: Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/iziToast") %>
<%: Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/noty") %>
<%: Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/js") %>
```

i removed it and it worked but i need the references so i tried place on body and it works. It asked me for script manager and now the page finally loaded with the control showing.

I read the same problem in the comments link. I placed a placeholder with runat=server around the bundle renders on header and it works!

Comment: I think you have code block somewhere in the markup (which not seen here yet), can you provide the markup for possible code blocks? I'm sure that this is not caused by `AjaxControlToolkit`, but caused by a code block which needs to be wrapped inside `asp:Placeholder`.

Comment: you have it inside UpdatePanel ?

Comment: possible duplicate - but I am not close it, please check it -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995274/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-blo

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate question but I'll leave the answer for someone who has same problem and gets lost in details.

Okay, after installing AjaxControlKit create a tab called AjaxControlKit on toolbox and right click and choose items and browse for AjaxControlKit dll in your package folder in your project solution explorer.

Add this inside  in web.config

```
    <handlers>
    <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" 
      path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd"
      type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, 
      AjaxControlToolkit"/>
</handlers>
```

and if you are rendering references on master page header with bundle do this

```
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <%: Styles.Render("~/Content/adminlte") %>
    <%: Styles.Render("~/Content/animate") %>
    <%: Styles.Render("~/Content/fontawesome") %>
    <%: Styles.Render("~/Content/iziToast") %>
    <%: Styles.Render("~/Content/noty") %>
    <%: Styles.Render("~/Content/css") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/jquery") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/adminlte") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/jqueryval") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/bounce") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/fontawesome") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/iziToast") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/noty") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/js") %>

</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

just create a placeholder around them. Works!