# ASP.NET "Controls cannot be modified [because it contains code blocks]..." error on one server but not another

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've got a web app that works on my local computer and our test server but is failing in production with this error:

> The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

I've read in a [couple](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2006/May/27/The-Controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-blocks-ie-) [places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778952/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-blo) that this can be fixed by changing `<%=...%>` to `<%#...%>`, but it intrigues me that the error comes up only in production.  What differences in configuration could be causing this?

Complete stack trace (note that it includes the Ajax Toolkit):

```
System.Web.HttpException: The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).
   at System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.Add(Control child)
   at AjaxControlToolkit.ScriptObjectBuilder.RegisterCssReferences(Control control)
   at AjaxControlToolkit.ExtenderControlBase.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: Is the control visible in development?

Comment: Yes.  It's actually a module for our CMS system, and it does this when its containing page is loaded.  Works fine everywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with something I find a lot easier and more straightforward -- while leaving the  tag in the header where it belongs.

First, start the code block with <%#  instead of <%=  :

```
<head id="head1" runat="server">
   <title>My Page</title>
   <link href="css/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="<%# ResolveUrl("~/javascript/leesUtils.js") %>"></script>
</head>
```

This changes the code block from a Response.Write code block to a databinding expression. Since <%# ... %> databinding expressions aren't code blocks, the CLR won't complain. Then in the code for the master page, you'd add the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      Page.Header.DataBind();    
   }
```

The DataBind method evaluates all the databinding expression(s) in your header at load time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove <% %> and add your attributes/texts from your code behind

Comment: I know how the is resolved elsewhere, but given that it works everywhere but production, I'm looking for a reason why it would be different.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your head content where "<%=" used in a placeholder like so:

```html
<asp:PlaceHolder Runat="server">

   <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/script.js") %>">       

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/style.css") %>"/>

</asp:PlaceHolder>
```