# Controls collection cannot be modified error? asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In web application, when I am trying to place a ajax calender extender I am getting this error:

`Error:The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>) .`

When I remove that ajax calender extender it is working fine, when I place ajax calender extender it is showing this error. Can you help me?

Comment: So have you searched for the error message and the 43000 hits weren't helpful? The first sounds already promising: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778952/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-bl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to answer, but still, Check :
[this post](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/12/aspnet-controls-collection-cannot-be.html)

The 2nd method worked for me.