# Pass value from code-behind to JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, code-behind

Trying to pass value (abc) from code-behind to JavaScript but the page fails and doesn't load.  Is there something wrong with the syntax?  I've noticed that normally the <%...%> is highlighted yellow but this is not the case in my code.

```
<script src="../Scripts/jqModal.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function() {    });

    $("a").click(function() {
    if (this.id == "optionalFeatures_Online") {
        var abc = "<%=Variable_codebehind %>";
    }
        });
</script>
```

Code Behind On_Load event:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        Variable_codebehind = "hello world"; 
    }
```

**Error from logfile:**

Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.Web.HttpException: The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Comment: The syntax look all right. Have you declared the variable `Variable_codebehind` anywhere? It has to be a `protected` or `public` member in the page class, or it's not reachble from the markup.

Comment: First, there's no point in `$().ready(function() {    });`. It need to wrap all you javascript to have any effect. Also you need to say what you want to wait to be ready... For example; `$(document).ready(function() { // Code here });`

Comment: You're screwed if there is a double quote in the `Variable_codebehind` contents.

Comment: What's the error. Please provide more context and what else you have tried to solve this issue.

Comment: Guff:  I've declared the variable as:  protected string Variable_codebehind;

Comment: smiledge:  sorry about that, I had code in there and pulled it out because it wasn't relevant to the question.

Comment: Lucero:  removed the double quotes (") and it still failed.

Comment: I've noticed something -- normally in Visual Studio the <%  %> are highlighted in yellow, but the code in the JavaScript function is not highlighted.  Here is the error from the logfile:  Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.Web.HttpException: The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Comment: Is the script block on a aspx/ascx? We'd need to see more of the code to tell if it is in the wrong place.

Comment: Is the script in the head tag?  If so, you can fix the error by moving it to the body tag.  According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778952/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-bl), changing the <%= to <%# (databinding) or wrapping it in a placeholder tag should do the trick.

Comment: The script is in the body tag.  Not clear about the syntax you recommend:  <%# (databinding)

Comment: The databinding syntax would be 'var abc = "<%# Variable_codebehind %>";' instead of 'var abc = "<%=Variable_codebehind %>";'.  Just change the '=' to a '#'.

Answer (score 0):

first bind the value to a hidden control

then get the value from the hidden control

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="../Scripts/jqModal.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {    
        $("a").click(function() {
            if (this.id == "optionalFeatures_Online") {
                var abc = <%=Variable_codebehind %>;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Code Behind On_Load event:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        Variable_codebehind = HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode("hello world", true); 
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting red underline on JavaScriptStringEncode -- do I need a USING statement?

Comment: You can easily look this up: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991914(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use Page.RegisterStartupScript and pass some variables from Code-Behind. Place the script in a .js file and call it on OnLoad method from the code-behind:

OnLoad CodeBehind:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "MyScript", String.Format("MyScript({0});", codeBehindVar));
```

MyScript.js

```
function MyScript(myVar)
{
   var self = this;
   $("a").click(function() {
   if (this.id == "optionalFeatures_Online") {
      var abc = self.myVar;
   }
}
```