# How to get elementbyid in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a masterpage in which i defined a function for `getElementById` .

```
function Clear() {
    document.getElementById('<%= NameTextBox.ClientID  %>').value = "";
    document.getElementById('<%= LastNameTextBox.ClientID  %>').value = "";
}
```

when i use this function in other page it is clearing the element value.

but when i use this code in masterpage, i get error :

> The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control
>   contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).]
 System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.Add(Control child) +9601391
AjaxControlToolkit.ScriptObjectBuilder.RegisterCssReferences(Control control) +691
AjaxControlToolkit.ScriptControlBase.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +44
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

if i change my code to :

```
document.getElementById('<%# NameTextBox.ClientID  %>').value = "";
```

i don't get error. but don't clear myelement.

Comment: take page source in browser and check the server side code rendered as you expected. or you can check in firebug console for any js error.

Comment: try `document.getElementById('ctl00_NameTextBox').value = "";`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778952/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-bl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have added mentioned js function in `<Head>` tag of master page.
Instead try adding your js function in `<form>` tag in master page at end.