# Reference stylesheet/spcript from User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I know this has been asked, but I have a more complicated issue than in other relevant questions.

I need to reference CSS and JS from my usercontrol.

References must be rendered inside `<head>` tag. For this reason I cannot use `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock`

Other solution I found:

```
    HtmlLink link = new HtmlLink();
    link.Href = "/path/style.css";
    link.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
    link.Attributes["rel"] = "stylesheet";
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(link);
```

However this ends up with ***"The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks"*** 
The problem is those code blocks are located in master page file which I don't have a control over. So workarounds suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778952/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-bl) are not possible. (E.g.: wrap code block in `<asp:placeholder ID="Placeholder1" runat="server">` or replace `<%=` with `<%#`

So considering above constraints, is it possible to place `<link href='path' />` and `<script src='path' />` inside `<head>` tag from User control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that worked for me:

Nesting Master page, and adding placeholder to nested Master page, then adding Literal Control as suggested by jon:

```
stylePlaceholder = ((PlaceHolder)((ContentPlaceHolder)Page.Master.Master.FindControl("HeadSection")).FindControl("phd_ControlsStyles"));

stylePlaceholder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(css + " href=\"http://" + cdn + "/Utils/Bundle/" + getCss() + ".css?v=" + settings["subVersion"] + "\" />"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a LiteralControl to the head.

```
Page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<script src'...'></script"));
```

Comment: Still produces same error: ***"The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)."***