# The Controls collection cannot be modified error when using asp Menu control

Tags: asp.net, menu, sitemap

So here is my problem:
I have a webpage that is using an asp:TreeView control and a sitemap to draw a menu.

```
<asp:TreeView ID="CatalogTreeViewControl" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsSiteMap">
</asp:TreeView>
<asp:SiteMapDataSource runat="server" ID="dsSiteMap" ShowStartingNode="False" SiteMapProvider="MyXmlSiteMapProvider"/>
```

This works like a charm, but I want to use the asp:Menu control instead of the TreeView, så I do this:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="CatalogTreeViewControl" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsSiteMap" Visible="False">
</asp:TreeView>

<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsSiteMap"></asp:Menu>

<asp:SiteMapDataSource runat="server" ID="dsSiteMap" ShowStartingNode="False" SiteMapProvider="MyXmlSiteMapProvider"/>
```

But this results in the following error:

> The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @MeNoMore Do not add the "aspdotnet" tag. There is already one named "asp.net"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this problem a long time back. I moved my javascript from the head tag to a form tag and it fixed the problem. These links helped me a lot :

["The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778952/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-bl)

http://leedumond.com/blog/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-blocks/

Comment: Thanks! Forgot that this control was used in a masterpage and that this masterpage included javascript.