# Httpexception The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks

Tags: asp.net, ajax, user-controls, httpexception

I try to add a user control by ajax but I have The same problem of [This One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778952/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-bl), and the suggested solution is [Remove <%= From head of page](http://leedumond.com/blog/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-blocks/), but my master page is:

[image: master page]

As you see there is not any `<%=` character in head of page, So where is the problem? why I get the error yet?

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put target elements in Panel or placeholder, and there is not any more error.