# Get session issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, session-state

I want to get session in jQuery(v 1.9.1).

I used the following code:

```
<script>
    var testUser = '<%= Session["User"] %>';
    alert(testUser);
</script>
```

But I get the following error:

> "The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control
>   contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)."
>
> "Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The Controls collection
>   cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <%
>   ... %>)"

Comment: Similar issue discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778952/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-bl

Comment: Tanks.I add 'Page.Header.DataBind()' in aspx and work fine :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getsession(){    
        var name = "<%= Session["test"]%>";
        alert('Session value = >' + name );
    };
</script>
```

OR you can try this

```
  // To Read
  $(function() {
  //Set the value to session
  $.session.set("userName", $("#uname").val());
  //Get the value to session
  alert($.session.get("myVar"));
  });
```

Comment: I add jquery.session.js and use $.session.get("myVar") but return 'undefined'

Comment: I Update answer please check it. This can be possible with javascript also. simply write "<%= Session["test"]%>"

Comment: tanks for answer but session set  server side

Comment: So now you can use javascript for that 

function getsession(){
var name = "<%= Session["test"]%>";
alert(name);
};

This will work fine with me. if this will work for you please accept my answer.

Comment: When i use  "<%= Session["test"]%>" i get above error but i add Page.Header.DataBind in PageLoad event then "<%# Session["test"]%>" work fine

Comment: you must try access session after set the session value. otherwise it will return undefined.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35741/discussion-between-ab-vyas-and-zsh)