# The controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks(i.e, <%...%>)

Tags: java, javascript, html, resolveurl

I have this problem which seems to be a common one, I have fixed the said issue but by fixing it I have made another issue and I'm hoping someone knows a way to fix it.

I have images on a webpage which need to resolve the URL before when I had the issue with code blocks it looked like

```
<td><img src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/")%>content/images/like_icon.png' alt="facebook" /></td>
```

I changed the <%= to <%# which fixed the code blocks but the image is not loading anymore.

```
<td><img src='<%#ResolveUrl("~/")%>content/images/like_icon.png' alt="facebook" /></td>
```

also I have done the same to the JavaScript on the page which has done the same type of thing, the java does nothing anymore!

any ideas on this issue would be a great help!

Thanks

Thomas James

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1176779/402037

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Fixed added a Div with runat="server" around all the content which fixed the issue