# Ajax Control Toolkit - ToolkitScriptManager is not a known element

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I downloaded the AjaxControlToolkit using nuget.exe then I tried to implement it in the project. As you can see with little success. I do not know why the system is not working properly.

Error:

```
Error   14  The type or namespace name 'ToolkitScriptManager' does not exist in the namespace 'AjaxControlToolkit' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

AjaxControlToolkit added to my project:

[image: In master page I added this:]

In master page I added this:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
```

Picture with problem:[image: assembly problem]

I try use this tutorials:
http://timscyclingblog.wordpress.com/2013/03/22/ajaxcontroltoolkit-version-7-0123-with-net-4-5/

http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2012/09/20/september-2012-release-of-the-ajax-control-toolkit

Comment: I added this ->  Page.Header.DataBind();  and in MasterPage I change (before <link href="<%="> after <link href="<%#">) and I come back to this <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778952/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-bl problem fixed

Comment: and also this I added to web.config <add namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also suffered from the same problem , the main thing is Nuget does not contain support for ToolkitScriptManager in VS 2010. All you need to do is to uninstall the dll file which you have downloaded from nuget and install it separately from [here](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/), then paste it in your project's bin folder and rebuild the solution..

Comment: Which part of the 700+ MB zip file do we paste in the project's bin folder?