# “The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks”

Tags: asp.net, webforms

While trying to insert controls in my page with the following block of code, i got this exception

> The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control
>   contains code blocks

```
Literal lite=new Literal();
lite.Text = @"<div class='cookieLaw_slidesharey'><a id='cookieLaw_slideshare' href='#'><img src='/img/content/cookielaw_slideshare.jpg'/></a></div>";
Control control = this.FindControl("PlaceHolder");
control.Controls.AddAt(0,lite);
```

I tried to follow the advices written in this thread:

["The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778952/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-bl)

Which are basically:

replacing `<%= %>` with `<%# %>`

And adding

`Page.Header.Databind()` in the page load

But i get the following exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Thank you for your help.

**PS: i'm using .NET 3.5**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your "PlaceHolder" has a `runat=server` attribute. That should already help. You can address that control by it's id then instead of using FindControl.

The reason why your `Page.Header.Databind()` is not working is probably because you don't have a head section with the runat=server like in the example you copied from. They were adding controls in the header there which can be slightly different.

Comment: Adding runat server to the header solves the problem but all my C# variables between <%# and %> are not recognized anymore ...

Comment: Just found my mistake. I had just one Placeholder for the whole page. I tried to add one in Head and one in body and it suddenly works